# Set IFrame allowfullscreen with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fullscreen

I tried to set allowfullscreen attribute to the iframe, but it doesn't work:

```
iframe.allowFullScreen = true
```

I checked it with chrome -> inspect element, but the iframe has no allowfullscreen attribute, after this code.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: depending on browser, it might be `mozAllowFullScreen` or `webkitAllowFullScreen`

Comment: `iframe.webkitAllowFullScreen = true` also doesn't works

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`iframe.setAttribute('allowFullScreen', '')`

Comment: Mind that `setAttribute` can fail in IE. For that one possible solution would be to set doctype as `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` (took from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329292/replace-setattribute-with-ie-compatible-script)

Answer (score -4):

It works for me if the word screen starts with a lowercase "s".

```
iframe.allowFullscreen = true;
```