# Replace setAttribute with IE compatible script

Tags: javascript, html, setattribute

I am trying to create a pop-up message that disables the rest of the screen until you confirm it, **only by using CSS and JavaScript** (and without the `alert` function).

Although http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx declares that `setAttribute` is supported in IE8 and higher, it does not seem to work correctly - well, actually it doesn't seem to work at all.

Here is my code:

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">

.overlay
{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.overlaytext
{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
padding-top: 5px;
background-color: #777777;
color: #000000;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

.overlaybutton
{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -30px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 20px;
width: 60px;
height: 25px;
border: solid;
border-color: #000000;
border-width: 1px;
background-color: #999999;
color: #000000;
font-size: 20px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showoverlay(message)
{
var overlay = document.createElement('div');
overlay.setAttribute('id','overlay');
overlay.setAttribute('class','overlay');
document.body.appendChild(overlay);

var overlaytext = document.createElement('div');
overlaytext.setAttribute('id','overlaytext');
overlaytext.setAttribute('class','overlaytext');
overlaytext.innerHTML = message;
document.body.appendChild(overlaytext);

var overlaybutton = document.createElement('input');
overlaybutton.setAttribute('type','button');
overlaybutton.setAttribute('id','overlaybutton');
overlaybutton.setAttribute('class','overlaybutton');
overlaybutton.setAttribute('value','OK');
overlaybutton.setAttribute('onclick','deleteoverlay()');
document.body.appendChild(overlaybutton);
}

function deleteoverlay()
{
var elem = document.getElementById('overlay');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
elem = document.getElementById('overlaytext');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
elem = document.getElementById('overlaybutton');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}

</script>

<body>

<input type="button" value="Show message" onclick="showoverlay('Message text')"/>

</body>
</html>
```

It works just fine in Firefox and Chrome, but IE (testing with IE9) seems to ignore the `setAttribute` method, because it only puts in the text and the button, but without the formatting (i.e. `class` was not applied) and also clicking the newly created button does not remove the objects (i.e. either `id` was not applied, or there is some additional incompatibility with portions of the code that remove the objects).

I tried to replace `setAttribute` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showoverlay(message)
{
var overlay = document.createElement('div');
overlay.id = 'overlay';
overlay.class = 'overlay';
document.body.appendChild(overlay);

var overlaytext = document.createElement('div');
overlaytext.id = 'overlaytext';
overlaytext.class = 'overlaytext';
overlaytext.innerHTML = message;
document.body.appendChild(overlaytext);

var overlaybutton = document.createElement('input');
overlaybutton.type = 'button';
overlaybutton.id = 'overlaybutton';
overlaybutton.class = 'overlaybutton';
overlaybutton.value = 'OK';
overlaybutton.onclick = 'deleteoverlay()';
document.body.appendChild(overlaybutton);
}

function deleteoverlay()
{
var elem = document.getElementById('overlay');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
elem = document.getElementById('overlaytext');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
elem = document.getElementById('overlaybutton');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}

</script>
```

But this time it does not even add the text and the button.

**So, how to make this script IE compatible, both showing all the elements and then removing them?**

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this as your doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and then put this in the head of the document

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

and then enjoy using `setAttribute` and a number of other features which this will allow to properly work on IE8+ environments.

Comment: Thanks, now I don't have to maintain two separate codes - for IE and for other browsers.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to set a class in your second example is:

```
overlaybutton.className = 'overlaybutton';
```

That will get classes working in IE.  As far as deleting elements goes, I'd recommend reformatting your event handling attachment like so:

```
overlaybutton.onclick = deleteoverlay;
```

Comment: This did the trick, perfect! Now the message window shows up properly and also disappears after clicking the button. One thing remains, though - the first div (which is supposed to cover the original content with transparent black area) does not appear in IE, do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Imortenson Never mind, found it. It was due to
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
Instead, I used
background-color: #000000;
opacity: 0.2;
filter: alpha(opacity=20);
and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue as well. If you are able to include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) on the site, you can use `$('#overlay').attr('class', 'overlay');`. jQuery is extremely useful for making cross-browser compatible code.

Comment: I am not familiar with jQuery. However, if that is the only option, I will have to have a look at it.

Comment: If it can be done with jQuery, it can be done without jQuery.