# Add a custom property to HTML element via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a custom element to Select html element.

```
 var sel=document.getElementById("sel1");
  sel.setAttribute("customprop","blabla");
```

In chrome it works, in IE8 it doesn't.

**NO JQUERY**

Comment: You mean custom _attribute_ (not _element_), right? Anyway, what are you trying to do with that?

Comment: Maybe you should try to use a `jQuery.attr('name', 'value')`? Provided that you use jQuery.

Comment: It should work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536739(v=vs.85).aspx. Is `sel` non-null?

Comment: @Paul Draper, no jquery

Comment: @yuris, you mean WojciechFrącz, no jquery?

Comment: Works well even in IE5 Quirks mode on IE 10, so it is hard to believe that it would not work on IE 8. Please provide sufficient code to actually demonstrate the problem and specify how you infer from the results that it does not work on IE 8.

Comment: Adding custom attributes violates HTML specifications. And it would be more natural to add a custom *property*, simply by an assignment like `sel.customprop = 'blabla'`.

Comment: Jukka K. Korpela, sel.customprop = 'blabla' didn't work neither in chrome or IE (i don't see it in View Source).

Comment: Just because it doesn't appear in the source in the IE Dev tools doesn't mean its not there. Have you tried setting it, then getting it? `elem.setAttribute('name','value')` then `console.log(elem.attributes)` to see if it's there? Also, when JS changes HTML elements in IE dev tools, you have to press the dev tools 'reload' button to refresh the source code to show any modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the question: [Replace setAttribute with IE compatible script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329292/replace-setattribute-with-ie-compatible-script)

It seems you need to add doctype on top of your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and then the following tag inside your head element to make setAttribute work:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```