# Cannot pass "onchange" listener to a checkbox via jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, checkbox

I am editing a website in Drupal 7, and using a custom JS file to add a bit of scripting functionality to a form that I created with the Webform module.

Basically, there is a checkbox that, if checked, will prevent the user from having to fill in redundant fields on the form if the information from one section also applies to the other section.

This is my code, for now I am just testing to see if the information gets passed between the functions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkbox = $("#edit-submitted-contact-information-pi-checkbox-1");
    checkbox.onchange = "checkPI(this);";
});

function checkPI(x) {
    if(x.checked) alert("Checkbox is checked");
    else alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
}
```

When I click the checkbox, however, nothing happens. I double checked and the JS script is being added to the page by Drupal (in the `.info` file I added `scripts[] = myjs.js` and also linked jQuery before that.

Upon doing other `alert()` tests, I found that it is finding the `check()` function from the document ready handler.

Am I missing something/not doing something a certain way?

**Also note:** I have to make sure this site works in IE 8, so I cannot use the `setAttribute()` method to add the `onchange` listener.

Comment: you can use `setAttribute` in IE8. here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329292/replace-setattribute-with-ie-compatible-script

Comment: OK, but do I have to use `setAttribute` to get this working at all?

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution...

The problem was that jQuery was treating the checkbox element as `[object Object]` instead of `[object HTMLInputElement]`. Therefore, to avoid the hassle, I just used plain old JavaScript to assign the functions and listeners and everything works now.