# durandal IE8 "undefined is null or not an object" error in viewEngine.js

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0

I get the above error in IE only.
the line that throws the error is apparently

```
element.setAttribute('data-view', viewId);
```

in viewEngine.js

```
createView: function(viewId) {
        var that = this;
        var requirePath = this.convertViewIdToRequirePath(viewId);
        var existing = this.tryGetViewFromCache(requirePath);

        if (existing) {
            return system.defer(function(dfd) {
                dfd.resolve(existing.cloneNode(true));
            }).promise();
        }

        return system.defer(function(dfd) {
            system.acquire(requirePath).then(function(markup) {
                var element = that.processMarkup(markup);
                element.setAttribute('data-view', viewId);
                that.putViewInCache(requirePath, element);
                dfd.resolve(element.cloneNode(true));
            }).fail(function(err) {
                that.createFallbackView(viewId, requirePath, err).then(function(element) {
                    element.setAttribute('data-view', viewId);
                    that.cache[requirePath] = element;
                    dfd.resolve(element.cloneNode(true));
                });
            });
        }).promise();
    },
```

edit:
I narrowed it down to the error happening between activate() and binding() in the lifecycle. Not sure if this is of any help, though.

edit2: upon further investigation i found that the processMarkup(markup) doesn't return a HtmlDivElement like it should and normally does for all other modules...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like IE8 has issues with the setAttribute method.

To solve try the following:

Use this as your doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and then put this in the head of the document

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Resource Link: [Replace setAttribute with IE compatible script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329292/replace-setattribute-with-ie-compatible-script)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I did have those tags set in my index.html.
And the script works fine with other modules of my application except for this one.
I'm sorry if my post was misleading and I didn't post any code from the module itself. I'll edit my post.
The first line I posted is part of the Durandal core file viewEngine.js I posted below it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake and it was not part of any javascript code.
the $.parseHTML() function in Durandals viewEngine.js only returns an object if the html markup supplied has syntactical correct HTML tags. I forgot to close one div at the very end of the view and that was the problem.

Comment: this solution worked for me. I was just putting a text without any html tags, so the viewEngine couldn't parse it as html