# How can I automatically add allowfullscreen to every new iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using codes like this in my blog:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/0eBDVy5nihM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And my question is simple, how can I automatically add `allowfullscreen` to every new iframe using javascript/jQuery?

Also, I presume the script should identify if there's the tag `allowfullscreen` added already.

I couldn't find a solution anywhere else.

Comment: How are you creating the iframes currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3774041/3764994
and here: [Set IFrame allowfullscreen with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034473/set-iframe-allowfullscreen-with-javascript)

To get all the iframe elements use getElementsByTagName(), then iterate over those with a for loop:

Something like this:

```
var i, frames;
frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i)
{
      // The iFrame
    if (!frames[i].hasAttribute("allowfullscreen")) {
        frames[i].setAttribute('allowFullScreen', '')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, this one is more complete so I'll leave this as best answer. those two empty quotes mean that it will add only to element that won't have the Allowfullscreen?

Comment: to elements that won't have*

Comment: Not all the attributes need value, for example, this case. So empty string is just to set the attribute, nothing else (http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value)

Answer (score 4):

Should be just this:

```
$('iframe').attr('allowFullScreen', '');
```

There is no need to check for allready set `allowfullscreen` as there will be no error if it is.

Comment: This trick works great, so I can validate my website without getting warning from validator... thanks!